# loopback 4 hasMany include filter Error 500

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

i am doing some practice with loopback 4, following the tutorial todo-list
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/todo-list-tutorial.html

i am trying to query data to gel todo-lists and related todos

GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/todo-lists?filter[include]=todos

i get an error 500 : relations "todos" not defined for the model TodoList

The route GET http://localhost:3000/todo-lists/1/todos works properly, but i'd like to retrieve lists and related todos.

I read many posts and the documentation but i do not understand what is wrong.

Thanks

Comment: @PanosK There's no json definition in lb4. You're referring to lb3.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I am a co-author and one of the current maintainers of LoopBack.*

LoopBack 4 does not yet support inclusion of related models when querying the database. You can join the discussion in the following GitHub issues:

- [Inclusion of related models #1352](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1352)
- [Include related models in "GET /mymodels" results #1889](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1889)

Please consider upvoting those issues by pressing the yellow thumbs-up button at the bottom of issue description.

---

**UPDATE - 2020-03-04**

These issues have been updated and now you can implement `hasMany` relations. Find more info [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/inclusion-of-related-models/)

Comment: Hope this is solved now. I'm starting a big project on Strongloop

Comment: Can anyone give update on this answer? @miroslav-bajtoš sir can you please?

Comment: Does support for include filter added to loopback 4?